# PPA error sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, 18.04, internet

I have an issue with the command

> $ sudo apt-get update

, it gives following errors:

```
  Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-cross-sbsa-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-cross-sbsa-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  InRelease
Ign:2 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  InRelease
Get:3 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-cross-sbsa-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  Release [563 B]
Err:4 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'apt.dockerproject.org'
Get:5 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  Release [564 B]                                                                                                                                      
Get:3 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-cross-sbsa-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  Release [563 B]                                                                                                                           
Get:5 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu1804-8.3.1.22  Release [564 B]                                                                                                                                      
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Get:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4,502 B]                                                                                                                                                
Ign:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease                                                                                                                
Get:11 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4,317 B]                                                                                                                           
Hit:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Hit:13 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:14 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release                                                                                                               
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:16 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                                                                                                                            
Hit:17 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossproject/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:19 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                         
Hit:20 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                 
Err:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                             
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
Hit:21 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                
Err:11 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                               
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:16 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease         
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 18DF3741CDFFDE29 philandro Software GmbH <info@philandro.com>
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done 
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 18DF3741CDFFDE29 philandro Software GmbH <info@philandro.com>
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

> ```
> $ uname -mrs
> ```
>
> Linux 5.4.0-105-generic x86_64

> 

```
> lsb_release -d
```

> Description:  Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Please advise! before this it was giving me a login loop issue, I was able to solve that but still stuck in this connection issue for the past 5days.

Update: I tried to purge PPA:

> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dnsmasq-base : Depends: libnettle6 (>= 3.4~) but it is not going to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed
 iputils-ping : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed
 libarchive13 : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed
 libgnutls30 : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed
 libhogweed4 : Depends: libnettle6 (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 librtmp1 : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have these following packages checked, do I need to uncheck PPA ones?

[image]

Comment: Not a connection issue. The issues you have is one PPA with expired signature key and others that aren't working and shouldn't have been added in the first place.

Comment: What is the safest way to solve this PPA issue? I saw lots of posts but I am scared that it will ruin my system.

Comment: Remove them... there are multiple ways to achieve this; and some apply only to desktop systems, others work on both desktop & server systems (you've given no details as to what you're using - only it's 18.04, not 18.04 Desktop, 18.04 Server etc).

Comment: @guiverc, I have ubuntu on my laptop, and I am not using a server. I actually tried that link but got a few other errors, did not work, I have never installed PPA, I am not sure how they came. I updated my post

Comment: Give this a go `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: It's kind of odd to state 'I've never installed ppa' when your system shows dozens of them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I believe it came when I was trying to install Nvidia drivers. Could I just uncheck those with PPA names and then uninstall PPA?

Comment: The safest thing to do is use the app `ppa-purge` but I don't know if you will be able to install it.

Comment: I installed ppa-purge, what do I need to do next?